# Extract referenced components (types, methods, etc) from their assembly into target assembly

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have a project that I want to share, but it references types, methods, helper extensions, and other components from multiple other assemblies that I've also written. However, I don't want to include the main project plus three other assemblies with their extensive code base, especially when I am only using only about, say, 5% of the code from the referenced assemblies. This would be helpful if I wanted to open-source a project while keeping it lightweight without the bloat.

It would be nice if there were a way to import into my executing assembly every referenced external assembly component. From the main assembly, a recursion would be done through the entire dependency tree, pulling in all referenced components and putting them in a path and file that reflects the original, but with only the components used by the executing assembly.

Is there a way to do this already or would I need to write my own VS extension? Seems like someone would have thought of this already.

Comment: You can't easily find anything because this so unnecessary. .NET assemblies usage is strongly powered by the "you don't pay for what you don't use" principle.  They are memory-mapped so stuff you don't use never gets loaded into memory.  The just-in-time compiler only compiles what you actually call, just in time.

Comment: @HansPassant I am not concerned about the size of the DLL. There could be times when you simply want to keep the source code itself lightweight. If I want to share a project that only uses 5% of all the code across several large external assemblies, I'd only want my main project to include that code so that I don't have to also include those external projects as part of the source.